# Changing font within Asymptote

Tags: luatex, typography, asymptote

I want to render the same text with a couple of different fonts, but when I do the following:

```
import settings;
import fontsize;
settings.tex="lualatex";
outformat="pdf";

size(9cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
defaultpen(0.1);

texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Courier New}");
draw(scale(0.1) * texpath("text"));
texreset();
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Arial}");
draw(shift(3, 0) * scale(0.1) * texpath("text"));
```

The resulting picture contains text written only in Courier New. If I change lines 11 and 13 to:

```
draw(scale(0.1) * texpath("text1"));
draw(shift(3, 0) * scale(0.1) * texpath("text2"));
```

The text renders correctly. What is going on here, and how can I render the same text with different fonts? I am using TeX Live 2017 on Windows 7. On a related note, LuaLaTeX generates errors when I try to render the text with labels like this:

```
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Courier New}");
label("text", (0,0));
texreset();
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Arial}");
label("text", (3,0));
```

The error:

```
asy -V font_change_test.asy
Process started (PID=4768) >>>
warning [unbounded]: y scaling in picture unboundedThis is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: C:/Users/Computer/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(using read cache: C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic C:/Users/Computer/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.157 secondsBabel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.

(./font_change_test_.tex (c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo(load luc: C:/Users/Comput
er/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-regular.luc)
)) (c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)(load luc: C:/Users
/Computer/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman12-bold.
luc)(load luc: C:/Users/Computer/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fo
nts/otl/lmroman12-italic.luc)))(load luc: C:/Users/Computer/.texlive2017/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/arial.luc)(load luc: C:/Users/Computer/.texl
ive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/arialbi.luc)(load luc: C:/User
s/Computer/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/arialbd.luc)(l
oad luc: C:/Users/Computer/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/ot
l/ariali.luc) (c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \pdfpagewidth 

l.24 \pdfpagewidth
                =251.189971bp

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \pdfpagewidth=
                 251.189971bp
! Undefined control sequence.
l.28 \pdfpageheight
                 =9.680209bp
(./font_change_test_.aux)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) [1{c:/texl
ive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./font_change_test_.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 386 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 4 attribute, 49 glue_spec, 4 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:45,3:3,4:6,5:26,6:34,7:18,8:1,9:19
<c:/Windows/fonts/arial.ttf>
Output written on font_change_test_.pdf (1 page, 16115 bytes).
Transcript written on font_change_test_.log.

C:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist\asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 87.10: runtime: shipout failed
C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:708: command failed with exit code 1:
asy -V font_change_test.asy
<<< Process finished (PID=4768). (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Comment: I guess what you might want to do is, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/121799), to introduce a main font as you did, and then use a second font with `\newfontfamily\myfont[<font features>]{<name of font>}` instead of the `texreset();`. I checked that this works if I use xelatex. However, I could not test it with lualatex.

Comment: [Perhaps related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350116/121799).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... and this is my MWE for xelatex, following the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/121799).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import settings;
import fontsize;
//settings.tex="lualatex";
outformat="pdf";

size(9cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
defaultpen(0.1);

texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Courier New}");
texpreamble("\newfontfamily\myfont{Arial}");
draw(scale(0.1) * texpath("text"));
draw(shift(3, 0) * scale(0.1) * texpath("{\myfont text}"));
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You obtain the same result if you compile

```
import settings;
import fontsize;
settings.tex="lualatex";
outformat="pdf";

size(9cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
defaultpen(0.1);

texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Courier New}");
texpreamble("\newfontfamily\myfont{Arial}");
draw(scale(0.1) * texpath("text"));
draw(shift(3, 0) * scale(0.1) * texpath("{\myfont text}"));
```

with `asy -V`, as you did.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why does my approach fail? The documentation says that `texreset()` resets all TeX macros. I'd like to do this switching for a large number of fonts, and this is a little bit of an inconvenient way of doing it. I'll accept your answer if nothing better gets suggested.

Comment: @blaze I guess that this is because `\usepackage` is not a macro and you can only load it in the document preamble but not within the document.

Comment: I just tried to load the fonts from a list and failed. LuaLaTeX complains: `string[] font_names = {"Courier New", "Arial"};
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}");
for (int i = 0; i < font_names.length; ++i)
{
 string preamble = "\newfontfamily\myfont" + (string)i + "{" + font_names[i] +"}";
 texpreamble(preamble);
 draw(shift((i + 1) % 5, -ceil((i + 1) / 5)) * scale(0.1) * texpath("{\myfont" + (string)i + " o}"));
}`

Comment: @blaze I guess that this is sort of the same problem (but I am by no means an expert). In this case, I'd like to argue that it does not make too much sense to do a loop. If I were to do a loop here, then this would be a loop that writes the asymptote lines along the lines of my answer.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I tried to follow the same logic as in your answer.

Comment: @blaze Does my answer work or not? What I meant is that, if you really do not want to write the various `texpreamble("\newfontfamily\myfont{...}");` by hand, you can write a shell script which does it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72280/discussion-between-blaze-and-marmot).