# Loading fonts from an array in Asymptote

Tags: fonts, luatex, typography, asymptote

Previous question:
[Changing font within Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412190/changing-font-within-asymptote/).
@marmot has successfully solved the case of two fonts but in reality I need to generate paths from letters of different fonts whose system names are stored in an array. Using the logic of the case of two fonts, I came up with this:

```lua
import settings;
import fontsize;
settings.tex="lualatex";
outformat="pdf";

size(9cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
defaultpen(0.1);

string[] font_names = {"Courier New", "Arial"};
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}");
for (int i = 0; i < font_names.length; ++i)
{
    string preamble = "\newfontfamily\myfont" + (string)i + "{" + font_names[i] +"}";
    string tp = "{\myfont" + (string)i + " a}";
    write(preamble);
    write(tp);
    texpreamble(preamble);
    draw(shift((i + 1) % 5, -ceil((i + 1) / 5)) * scale(0.1) * texpath(tp));
}
```

Pending question: I tried the following but it failed to switch the font:

```
import settings;
import fontsize;
settings.tex="lualatex";
outformat="pdf";

size(9cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
defaultpen(0.1);

texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Courier New}");
draw(scale(0.1) * texpath("text"));
texreset();
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Arial}");
draw(shift(3, 0) * scale(0.1) * texpath("text"));
```

What does `texreset()` do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue was that TeX doesn't support numbers in macro names, so I'm now forming the font identifier based on the binary representation of the index of the font name.

```
import settings;
import fontsize;
settings.tex="lualatex";
outformat="pdf";

size(9cm);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
defaultpen(0.1);

string bin(int n)
{
    int i;
    string res;
    for (i = intMax; i > 0; i = (int)(i / 2)) {
    if (AND(n, i) != 0) { res += "a"; } else { res += "b"; } }
    return substr(res, 48);
}

string[] font_names = {"Courier New", "Arial"};
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}");
for (int i = 0; i < font_names.length; ++i)
{
    string preamble = "\newfontfamily\myfont" + bin(i) + "{" + font_names[i] +"}";
    string tp = "{\myfont" + bin(i) + " o}";
    write(preamble);
    write(tp);
    texpreamble(preamble);
    draw(shift((i + 1) % 5, -ceil((i + 1) / 5)) * scale(0.1) * texpath(tp));
}
```